# php memory is increasing while running the progrm

Tags: php

i am running an program that increases the memory while executing each time...
i am getting the links from the database and parsing for contents...

```
<?php

     include "aa.php";
$ex="all_link";

$cd="crawled_link";


$sql="SELECT * FROM $ex";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

$i=1;
$j=1;
$temp=0;

while($count > 0)
 {


    $sql="SELECT * FROM $ex where num='$i'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    $rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);      
    $a=$rows['link'];


    $sql="SELECT * FROM $cd where link='$a'";
    $result1=mysql_query($sql);
    $rows1=mysql_num_rows($result1); 
    flush();
    if(!$rows1)
    { 
        $cdurl=trim($rows['link']);

        start_scan($cdurl);        
    }
    else
    {

    }


    $sql="SELECT * FROM $ex";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    $temp=mysql_num_rows($result);

    $count=$temp-$i;
    $i++;
    flush();
 }   

mysql_close();
```

while it execute first time the memory is 4 MB and after that it increases up 25o and greater is there is any way to get out of it....

Comment: Your code makes very little sense. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I can't see much wrong with it. The only thing i'd advise is to use include_once instead of just include. This as the name says only includes the file once. I'm not saying your including it more than once but I think it's safer that way.

Comment: @Ash Really? From the looks of it, he/she could've done everything with 1 (one) query. Yet there are 3 queries inside a while loop; the last one being totally unnecessary. It just gets the count, which he/she already prior to the start of the loop. The first query in the loop also useless, since it's been queried before - without the condition on num. And the 2nd query probably could've been removed if he/she used a JOIN.

Answer (score 2):

Memory is freed up:

- When you tell it to
- When you leave a function
- When the script ends

Situation 1 occurs when you use `unset()`, `mysql_free_result()`, or other resource-destroying functions that explicitly clear up after your variables. Situation 2 clears up resources implicitly - any variable that leaves scope, i.e. is no longer applicable, gets cleared up for you. Finally, situation 3 frees up all script-related resources implicitly.

Note that you can get memory usage with [`memory_get_usage`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php). Once you free up some resources with `unset`, etc you can check out the difference, here is an example:

```
echo memory_get_usage() . <br />;
unset(......);
unset(......);
unset(......);
echo memory_get_usage();
```

**Listen to all errors, big and small**

Always set your PHP error level to the most verbose level, E_ALL. All too often people don't realise that PHP is outputting various complaints about variables not being set, etc, which you can just do away with entirely by cleaning up your code. While you are editing your php.ini file, it would also help to disable all the extensions you don't use - they are just chewing up memory otherwise.

Comment: @Ram: Like sAc said, call `mysql_free_result()` when you don't need the query any more. Also I see nothing wrong in the little script besides that. However, you call a mysterious `start_scan()` which looks like it's fetching web pages. You might want to check it, again bearing in mind what sAc said about memory freeing.